# Entity Framework - Compatibilidade com Bancos

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estava lendo um [artigo](http://www.devmedia.com.br/usando-mysql-com-ado-net-entity-framework-4-parte-i/21667) que demonstra o método de utilização do Entity Framework para conexão com banco MySQL, porém, o artigo demonstra técnicas bem diferentes das que utilizo. (MVC).

Atualmente minhas aplicações se baseiam em bancos MS SQL, utilizando método Code First.

Utilizo a seguinte estrutura de ConnectionString:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BancoDados" connectionString="Data Source=sqlserver.hospedagemdesites.ws;Initial Catalog=database;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=login;Password=senha" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Como a licença mais ampla do MySQL nos permite baratear um pouco o custo da aplicação, gostaria saber se consigo migrar minhas aplicações e ainda utilizar os recursos do Entity Framework, como o citado Code First.

Comment: Talvez esse link te ajude: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277677/dynamic-mysql-database-connection-for-entity-framework-6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Gostaria de saber se consigo migrar minhas aplicações e ainda utilizar os recursos do Entity Framework, como o citado Code First.

Sim, consegue. O pacote NuGet abaixo concede este suporte:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySQL.Data.Entities/

É preciso também registrar o *provider* no seu arquivo `Web.config` da raiz como padrão:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Feito isso, basta usar seu contexto normalmente:

```
public class MeuContext: DbContext
{
    public MeuContext() : base("BancoDados")
    {
    }

    // Registre seus DbSets aqui
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O MySQL é um dos bancos que o *Entity Framework* com o [Data Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/data/dd363565.aspx) oferecido pelo [site do MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/), funciona corretamente. A função desses [Data Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/data/dd363565.aspx) é prover a diferenças imposta nos bancos de dados, principalmente funcionalidades particulares

**Exemplo:** `Top` em SQL Server, `limit` e `offset` em MySQL, então o [Data Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/data/dd363565.aspx) ficam responsável por essas mudanças e o Entity Framework trabalha de forma transparente com esses Bancos.

Em relação a Bancos de Dados, o *Entity Framework* trabalha com todos o que difere são os [Data Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/data/dd363565.aspx) que em alguns casos não funcionam, mas existem alguns pagos que são as alternativas. Deixando bem claro que a culpa ("ou falta de vontade") não é do pessoal de desenvolvimento do *ORM Entity Framework* e sim das empresas que são detentoras dos direitos dos Sistemas Gerenciadores de Banco de Dados de não oferecerem os [Data Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/data/dd363565.aspx) corretamente.

Só reforçando, com MySQL você não terá problemas tenho 3 sites até o momento rodando ASP.Net MVC com MySQL, funciona muito bem.

Existem um que pago o [Devart](http://www.devart.com/dotnetdatabaseconnectivity.html) com vários Data Providers.

**Instalação:**

Baixo o pacote do site: [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) e instale normalmente em seu computador. Na hora da criação a janela vai aparecer o Data Provider do Mysql igual exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora é só sigar os passos que ele faz para você todas as configurações. Eu gosto de trabalhar com Database First, ou seja, construo o banco no MySQL e depois gero as entidades pela ferramenta!

Comment: Por gentileza, você poderia dar um exemplo? Em pesquisa encontrei isso: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySQL.Data.Entities/ que é instalável via NuGet.

Comment: @RafaelBarbosa eu instalo pelo que está no site!, porque, ele me mostra um janela de configuração que se torna o trabalho mais simples possível!

Comment: @RafaelBarbosa, eu editei! acho que agora você consiga fazer as configurações...