# Erro Conexão MySQL asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando trabalhar com um banco MySQL em minha aplicação. Porém, estou obtendo o seguinte erro:

> Keyword not supported: 'data source'.

Realizei todos os procedimentos relacionados nessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28830/entity-framework-compatibilidade-com-bancos)
Mas de forma resumida, realizei essa instalação em meu `NuGet`

`PM> Install-Package MySQL.Data.Entities`

**Web.config**

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="BancoDados" connectionString="Data Source=mysql01.hospedagemdesites.ws;
         Initial Catalog=catalog;
         User ID=userid;
         Password=password;"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**App.config** (RepositorioEF)

```
 <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

**Contexto**

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class Contexto : DbContext
{
    public Contexto()
        : base("BancoDados")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<item> item { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Data Source` é para SQL Server. Modifique para:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="BancoDados" connectionString="Server=mysql01.hospedagemdesites.ws;
         Database=catalog;
         Uid=userid;
         Pwd=password;"
         providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Alterei o `provider` como havia me recomendado na outra pergunta. Com ele assim : `providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"` consegui avançar e me deparar agora com outro erro. `Unknown column 'Extent1.Nome' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 1):

Coloque assim:

***A ConnectionString direto no Construtor***

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class Contexto : DbContext
{
    public Contexto()
        : base("Server=mysql01.hospedagemdesites.ws;Database=catalog;Uid=userid;Pwd=password;")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<item> item { get; set; }
}
```