# Conexão Entity Framework com Mysql

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

Fiz os procedimentos apontados nessas perguntas:

[Entity Framework - Compatibilidade com Bancos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28830/entity-framework-compatibilidade-com-bancos)

[Erro Conexão MySQL asp.net MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30200/erro-conex%C3%A3o-mysql-asp-net-mvc)

Instalei o MySQL.Data.Entities.

Meu web.config ficou assim:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BancoDados" connectionString="Server=xxx;
         Database=xxx;
         Uid=xxx;
         Pwd=xxx;"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Porém ao executar `Add-Migration` dispara o seguinte erro:

> Keyword not supported: 'server'.

Tentei trocar o `providerName` para `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`, disparou o seguinte erro:

> The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is
>   either not registered in the machine or application config file, or
>   could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.

Ao instalar o .Net Connector erro:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices
>   providerServices, DbConnection connection)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Tuple`3
>   k)    at
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection
>   connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection
>   providerConnection)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ModelBeingInitialized()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext
>   context, XmlWriter writer)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(XmlWriter
>   w)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1
>   writeXml)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState
>   existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   configuration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   migrationsConfiguration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
>   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate
>   callBackDelegate)    at
>   System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Scaffold(String
>   migrationName, String language, String rootNamespace, Boolean
>   ignoreChanges)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name,
>   Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command) Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Instalou o .Net Connector? http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: Não, apenas instalei o MySQL.Data.Entities.

Comment: Então instale e repita o teste, por favor.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, o seguinte erro: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Esse erro pode ser qualquer coisa. Você pode colocar por favor a Stack Trace no corpo da pergunta?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, pronto!

Comment: [Nesta resposta aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602114/mysql-connector-6-8-2-rc-entity-framework-6-and-code-first) o autor da pergunta tem o mesmo problema que você. Pode ser ou um problema da configuração do `web.config` ou então é o connector que tem algum bug. Na resposta mais votada tem como expandir essa configuração. Poderia verificar, por favor?

Comment: Obrigado @CiganoMorrisonMendez, consegui... Porém agora estou com outro problema... http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40138/publicar-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-entity-framework-mysql

Comment: O que foi feito pra resolver? Ainda quero adicionar a resposta.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, Eu instalei o .net Connector e deixei a connectiostring assim: `<add name="BancoDados" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=xxxx; port=3306; Initial Catalog=bancoMySQL; uid=usuarioMySQL; pwd=qwe123qwe;" />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sintetizando o que foi colocado em comentário:

## 1. Instalar o .NET Connector do MySQL

> http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

## 2. Configurar o arquivo `web.config` da seguinte forma:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BancoDados" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=xxxx; port=3306; Initial Catalog=bancoMySQL; uid=usuarioMySQL; pwd=qwe123qwe;" />
</connectionStrings>

<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```